# imagegettfbbox() height calculated by the return values cut out the text like q, p in php gd

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

```
public function createImage($text,$w,$h,$color,$id,$no){
        $source = "uploads/jersey/img".$id."_".$no.".png";

        $font_size = 20;
        $font_file = 'fonts/arial.ttf';

        // Retrieve bounding box:
        $type_space = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font_file, $text);

        // Determine image width and height, 10 pixels are added for 5 pixels padding:
        $image_width = abs($type_space[4] - $type_space[0]);
        $image_height = abs($type_space[5] - $type_space[1]);

        // Create image:
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($image_width, $image_height);


        // Allocate text and background colors (RGB format):
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagecolortransparent($image, $text_color);

        // Fix starting x and y coordinates for the text:
        $x = 0; // Padding of 5 pixels.
        $y = $image_height; // So that the text is vertically centered.

        // Add TrueType text to image:
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, hexdec($color), $font_file, $text);


        imagepng($image,$source);
        imagedestroy($image);
        return  $source;
    }
```

im creating the image with the width and height returned by the imagegettfbbox(), and inserted text into it.
but the text is cutting out. i know im missing calculation in height.
 the created image is like this [image]

how to calculate the height?